# Media Source Extension with an unfragmented mp4 file

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, media-source

I'm attempting to use media source extensions to play a mp4 file. The example that I'm following is here: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html

I have this example working with both webm videos, and fragmented mp4 videos. Do media source extensions not work with unfragmented mp4 videos? Shouldn't I be able to manually append chunks of the video to the source buffer? It looks like the appending works, but the video won't play.

Answer (score 3):

Media source extensions will not work with "regular" MP4.
See 
[supported formats.](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/byte-stream-format-registry.html)

The only version of MP4 that is listed there is ISO BMFF Byte Stream Format which is the so called fragmented MP4 format.

You can convert your MP4 to fragmented MP4 using tools such MP4Box or FFmpeg.